# C program output file gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, c

I have created a C program and made an executable under Linux.

Right now, I open the executable by going first to gnome-terminal and then type

```
./<filename>
```

I want to create a shortcut icon on the desktop for the same executable. That is, if I click on the program shortcut, it should open gnome-terminal with an `"<executable>"` automatically.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not a programming question, voting for moving to Super User.

Comment: Have a look at the [Desktop Entry specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your GNOME desktop, choose 'Create Launcher' and then specify the location of your program (assuming it's not in $PATH, if it is, then you don't need to specify the whole path, you can just give )

Make sure you have 'run in terminal' selected, and you'll be able to see the output of the program.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GNOME.html#LAUNCHER

Comment: I am sorry for not adding more details.

I am working in ARM linux platform. I do not have launcher application.